# POSTMAN API Request of (POST) is not working

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, postman

I am new to node.js and facing some errors. I am trying to send a POST request on Postman but it's giving me blank with no data in it. And also I checked if my data is valid or not then I got, the data I am sending is valid. Can anyone suggest me?

This is my index File(index.js):

```js
   const express = require("express");
   const app = express();
   const dotenv = require("dotenv");
   const mongoose = require("mongoose");

   //Import Routes
   const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
   const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");

   dotenv.config();

   //connect to DB
   mongoose.connect(
     process.env.DB_CONNECT,
     { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true },
     () => console.log("connected to DB!!")
   );

   //Middleware
   app.use(express.json());
   //Route Middlewares
   app.use("/api/user", authRoute);
   app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);

   //PORT NUMBER
   const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // default port to listen

   // start the Express server
   app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
   });
```

This is my Auth file(auth.js):

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require("../validation");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("register");
  //Lets validate a data before we make a user
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Checking if the user is already in the database
  const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (emailExist) return res.status(400).send("Email Already Exists");

  //HASH THE PASSWORD
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  //Create a New User
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword,
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send({ user: user._id });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  //Lets validate a data before we make a user
  const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Checking if the email exists in the database
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Email is Not Found");

  //Check if password is correct
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Password");

  //Create  and assign a Token
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
  res.header("auth-token", token).send(token);
});

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see:

[image]

I am not able to send data and fetch it with the POST request, DB is connected too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(req.body)`.
If your `req.body` is empty then you need to add a package `body-parser` in middleware(index.js file).

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```